# How to use placeholders in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, variables, placeholder, substitution

In Objective C, I am trying to use a for statement to hide several images, instead of typing the code for each one. I'm not sure how to substitute the variables into the name of my UIImageViews. This is how I originally tried to do it but I'm not sure if I need to use placeholders (%_) instead. Thanks!

```
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            RowjTilei.hidden = YES; //example: Row1Tile3.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't. You use an array instead.

Comment: Having an ivar for each tile object is a bad bad idea. Try storing them in a 2-dimensional Array. (Also, what you're trying can be achieved using KVC but it's not what KVC is built for)

Comment: Store image views into `IBOutletCollection` array.

Comment: You should use an array, but you may also do `NSString *nameVar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row%dTile%d", i,j];UIImageView *imgView = [self valueForKey:nameVar]; [imgView setHidden:YES];`

Comment: @Larme Yap, it's nice to point out that this is actually *possible* (albeit not the best idea) to do in Objective-C.